# Hide some phrase in vueJs project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a [RealWord App](https://github.com/EricSimons/realworld) for Vue project. I'm trying to find a way to hide the phrase "test", so that it cannot show any article with the "test" phrase.

TagList.vue Component:

```html
<template>
  <ul class="tag-list">
    <li
      class="tag-default tag-pill tag-outline"
      v-for="(tag, index) of tags"
      :key="index"
    >
      <span v-text="tag" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "TagList",
  props: {
    tags: Array
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide tags that contain "test", use a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to get a [filtered array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of `tags[]`:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    filteredTags() {
      return this.tags.filter(tag => tag !== 'test')
    }
  }
}
```

Then, update your `v-for` to use this computed prop:

```html
<li v-for="(tag, index) of filteredTags">
```

Comment: i think it works very well but there is error says "Error in render: "ReferenceError: tags is not defined"